# RequireJS not correctly initializing modules

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, require

When I visit my website it regularly works fine. Other times I get an error from Javascript that leads me to believe the object or function I've *required* has not been correctly initialized by requirejs at the point of use.

As an example this is the top of one of my modules:

[image: Top of module]

And here is the value of the Backbone variable at this point in the code.

[image: Chrome Debugger Output]

Note that an object is returned with a load function. This behaviour seems to arbitrarily occur on various defined and required modules (not just Backbone).

I can confirm that the define method on the modules is called (where that module is AMD compatible. Backbone is shimmed.) but the function passed to the define call is not called.

My guess is that requirejs is still initializing it in some way, but I thought that the require calls are synchronous and will only return once the module is ready for use.

Any help or guidance appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've used RequireJS for years and I've never run into the behavior you report. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: If I could do that I'm fairly certain I would have solved it by now :) Unfortunately it's a large enterprise app with many moving parts so I'm struggling to reproduce it in that way.

Comment: Hmm... lots of people post questions about [tag:requirejs] that contain a [mcve] and yet their problem is not solved. So there's proof right there that it is possible to post a MCVE without having solved the problem.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate that. I was trying to imply that the problem is likely related to the complexity of the app.

Answer (score -1):

After much digging I was able to determine the load method came from a dependency of the Google Visualisation library, WebFontLoader.

Details on the possible cause of the bug are here:
https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2070

To fix I took the provided suggestion of using the frozen loader but with version 41, not 43.